# What Situations is Saving a Game to Main Memory for?

Tags: c++, architecture, unreal-4, savegame

---

I've been reading through Unreal's 'Saving and Loading' guide: [Link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/SaveGame/index.html)

Within, they present a capability to save a game to main memory rather than secondary storage:

[image: Picture of Save Game to Main Memory section on Unreal documentation website]

---

I haven't found any information on where this would ever be used.

The only situation I can fathom for this being useful is to keep data about other load zones in memory so that travelling through load screens into these zones is quicker.

---

Why, When and Where is this technique of saving to Main Memory used instead of saving to Secondary Storage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes you might want to store your savegame data somewhere else than on the users hard drive. You might offer a cloud save service, for example. In that case you would use `SaveDataToMemory` to create a savegame in a memory buffer and then send that memory buffer to a server via network.

Another possible use-case could be to always keep the last savegame in memory so you can restore it faster in case the player quickloads or dies. Using `LoadGameFromMemory` when you already got the savegame in memory can be much faster than loading the game from the hard drive.

Comment: +1, quicksave/quickload is the first that came to mind for me.